# Entity Framework aliasing in join operation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, join

I am creating a query in Visual Studio for retrieving data from a SQL Server.

Can I, and if so how, use aliasing on variables in `.Join()`s?

I have something like:

```
var query =
    context.tblOne
    .Join(
        context.tblTwo,
        varOne => varOne.ParamFromVarOne,
        varTwo => varTwo.ParamFromVarTwo,
        (varOne, varTwo) => varOne)
```

Can I somehow access the "varOne" and "varTwo" objects and their parameters outside of the join? I need other parameters from varOne and two in my `.Where()` clause to filter the search result.

Is there perhaps another way to query for this?

I have 10 `.Join()`s and on those joins and after the `.Where()` I want to create a new JSON object.toList() using the

```
.Select(x => new {x.param1, x.param2, x.param3}) etc
```

A more abstract way of explaining what I want to do is something like:

```
.Where(x => x.Param1 <= compareVariable1 && 
    x.Param2 >= compareVariable1 &&
    y => y.Param1 == compareVariable2 &&
    z => z.Param1 == compareVariable3)
```

In other words, a `.Where()` clause with multiple table-records from which I compare the column values to method parameters/arguments.

Can I perhaps concatenate the Joins and if so how do I go about this?

Comment: Have you considered to write the Linq in query syntax instead of using method syntax with lambda?
that way you can use the "let" clause https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause

Comment: You seem to be taking the hardest path. Query syntax will make all that aliasing transparent. And EF navigation properties will almost eliminate the joins.